# How do you obfuscate APK or protect APK for Android that is published with Flash Pro CC ?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apk, obfuscation, flash-cs6

I created an application for Android smartphones using Flash Pro CC.

I don't know much about obfuscating APK files but I heard that APK can be easily decompiled and therefore my AS file sourcecode is vulnerable. So I started searching on google and found that ProGuard does obfuscation. But it's for Eclipse so I guess i can't use ProGuard for my app which is created using Flash Pro CC. Is there any way to obfuscate my APK? or is there any other way to protect my APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obfuscate your swf file and then just recompile the APK. You can obfuscate as3 using: http://www.kindi.com/, http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/.... or others. Note that these tools might cause performance issues and errors so be sure to test the final version.